# Is data lost when Memgraph that runs on Docker is restarted?

Tags: memgraphdb

I want to run the Memgprah platform inside Docker (on Windows 10 machine, if it is important). What will happen if I restart my computer or Docker service? Will my data be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker containers don’t persist data by default (all changes are lost when the container is stopped). But here is a way to avoid data loss.

You need to use local volumes to store the data permanently, which is why Memgraph is started with the `-v` flag:

```
docker run -p 7687:7687 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph
```